# Setting ftp on linux 12.04 lts (Amazon Instance) for Drupal installation

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ftp, drupal

In these days I'm striving trying to set a proper ftp connection with my Amazon Instance, aimed for Drupal 7.

It mounts a Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it's a Micro Instance.

I tried a lot of vsftpd guides, testing several different configurations on the vftpd.conf file. Nothing seems to matter. I tried to configure an user with the documentation I've found on the official Ubuntu forum at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076620

Nothing. When I state the user and pass I've setted, Drupal refuses the connection straight away; it doesn't even seems to try it out. Filezilla attempts a connection instead, but it runs out of time and it stops sending requests; I don't think it's a matter of timeout_settings thou, I believe there might be something wrong with the ftp itself.

I believed I could have misconfigured some setting on the machine, so I tried running another instance. FTP seems not to work properly on this kind of system. I wonder if that is because of the encrypted key it needs in order to establish a connection.

I've also read quite a lot of documentation about FTP, and I believe this guide is well worthy for everyone who has just approached the server side of life, like me :)

What do you think I am not considering in my settings?

Answer (score 1):

I [already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880989/setting-ftp-on-linux-12-04-lts/14882523#14882523). You need to open ports 20-21, and 1024-1048 in your security group. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052875/setting-up-ftp-on-amazon-cloud-server

Comment: You are right, I started working on it a second after I read your answer, which was after I posted this question :) I'm working on it, cheers :)

Comment: It goes quite well from ssh. It logs succesfully with the user and the pass I gave; the problem is when I try to reach the ftp with filezilla; it times out me while logging this message out "227 Entering Passive Mode (23,*,*,67,4,4). I put the stars because I'm well aware that this is my ip. I'm sure this is an Amazon's firewall issue, which is not letting the passive connection in, but I can't find no help and I'm quite new to servers. Keep trying out thou

Comment: Did you try the entirety of that tutorial, step by step? FTP on Amazon is entirely possible - although you shouldn't be using it for anything secure, as the password's transferred in the clear.

Comment: Key parts from that tutorial will be `pasv_min_port=1024` `pasv_max_port=1048`, most likely.

Comment: Sure I followed everything, setted all the ports both on server's firewall and vsftpd.conf file. It has a problem when trying to create the directories' tree; it goes on until it says that it was impossible to read the directory's folder. I wonder if this is a permission issue, but I don't want to put all of my folders on 777. What should i try?

Comment: Well, what user's trying to read the directory, and which one owns it? You'll probably need to `chown` the directory.

Comment: Nothing seems to matter. I just tried setting the starter root and giving it 777 permission mode (I don't really need to manipulate files outside that dir via ftp, so I can afford it). Nothing changes. Then I tried giving the user is connecting via chown the ownership of that, but still nothing changes. I don't say I'm desperate, but I almost am

Comment: Ok I managed to access the ftp server, summoning "passive" on the ftp prompt in the shell. Problem is that now I've been located on the "/" folder and everything seems empty :| I didn't think it would have been so difficult to set up a simple ftp daemon

Comment: That's typical for FTP. Users are usually chrooted (see the vsftpd.conf file for configuration options) to their own home directory. You should closely read and ensure you understand vsfptd's configuration... and again, you really shouldn't be using this for anything secure. SFTP is a much better option in nearly all cases.

Comment: You are pretty right I assume, but i need it just for a few span of time, where I need it for production, in order to move the css file into the right directory. I couldn't jail the user I made to the folder i choose, I don't know why, so I had to take chroot_local_user=NO and now I can access, but i reckon it is quite dangerous. Thanks for everything guyz